# could not view page html content in visual studio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have working on one page template.My code is not working.It does not throw any error.

My HTML code

```
<div id="support" class="doublediagonal">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-heading scrollpoint sp-effect3">
                <h1>Support</h1>
                <div class="divider"></div>
                <p>For more info and support, contact us!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 scrollpoint sp-effect1">
                            <form role="form">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 contact-details scrollpoint sp-effect2">
                            <div class="media">
                                <a class="pull-left" href="#" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">4, Some street, California, USA</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media">
                                <a class="pull-left" href="#" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                                        <a href="mailto:support@oleose.com">support@oleose.com</a>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media">
                                <a class="pull-left" href="#" >
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x"></i>
                                </a>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h4 class="media-heading">+1 234 567890</h4>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS 
i am here attached my css code
    /* support section */

```
div#support {
 padding: 0 0 150px 0;
}
div#support .media {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
div#support .media i.fa {
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-ms-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
 border-radius: 50%;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
  width: 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
 }
div#support .media .media-heading {
 padding-top: 15px;
 font-weight: 300;
 }
div#support .media .media-heading a {
font-weight: 400;
}
```

how to solve this.i could not view anything in ocal host when running in visual studio

Comment: It's working perfectly fine. See https://jsfiddle.net/qzjqkpk0/

Comment: Do you have a public URL so we can check it?

Comment: I think you have problem with running your localhost webserver rather then with your code. How to you check if you code is working?

Comment: I dont have any idea ..a running this code in visual studio 2010

Comment: please help me to solve.its simple line of code not working in visual studio